# Android - Checkbox not responding to clicks inside of FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm working on a music player application, and I've created a FrameLayout which works as a "card," displaying information about each song (album art, title, artist, etc.) I'm trying to add checkboxes in this card, which I plan to customize to create upvote and downvote buttons. However, the checkboxes within the card do not respond to clicks. If I draw a checkbox in the main activity of the application (where I'm drawing the cards), it works fine.

Here is the onDraw() method of the card view ("MusicCardView"):

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


    //Draw the voting controls
    try {

        CheckBox upvoteButton = new CheckBox(getContext());
        upvoteButton.setX(20);
        upvoteButton.setTop(-60);
        upvoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Is the button now checked?
                Log.d("MainActivity", "upvote clicked");
            }
        });
        CheckBox downvoteButton = new CheckBox(getContext());
        downvoteButton.setX(20);
        downvoteButton.setTop(-150);
        downvoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Is the button now checked?
                Log.d("MainActivity", "downvote clicked");
            }
        });

        upvoteButton.draw(canvas);
        downvoteButton.draw(canvas);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MusicCardView", "exception", e );
    }

}
```

The xml of the main activity ("PartyActivity"):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.musique.PartyActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/main_linear_view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp">
        <com.musique.MusicCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/now_playing_view"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            app:exampleColor="#000000"
            app:songTitle="Money"
            app:artist="Pink Floyd"
            app:album="The Dark Side of the Moon"
            app:exampleDimension="18sp"
            app:exampleDrawable="@drawable/darkside"
            app:exampleString="example" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/controller_space"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/query"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Search"
            android:background="#5eca99"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvData"/>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:id="@+id/main_scroll_view">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/scroll_child">

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And an example of a MusicCardView being the draw in PartyActivity

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
MusicCardView v = (MusicCardView) vi.inflate(R.layout.music_card_template, null);
v.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 210));
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.scroll_child);
v.setSongAttributes(song);
new RetrieveArtTask(v).execute(song);
Log.d("PartyActivity", "SongAttributes Set");
linearLayout.addView(v);
```

I've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170924/custom-listview-with-checkbox-not-responding-to-clicks) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217613/click-event-not-working-inside-frame-layout), but had no luck with the solutions posted, and would greatly appreciate any advice you might have.

Comment: `upvoteButton.draw(canvas);` this is wrong: instead of "drawing" your check boxes you have to use `ViewGroup#addView` and they will draw themselves and will be responding to your clicks

Comment: Okay I am not answering your question but wondering where will you user upArrow and downArrow drawable ?

Comment: @AJay Whoops, that was old code. Edited to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw the controls directly to the canvas they are basically just bitmaps, you need to add them to the view hierarchy (activity/fragment layout) for them to receive touch events.

As a side note, it's a big no-no to instantiate things in onDraw, especially views.

Comment: or dispatch the touch event to checkbox

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask why it's bad to instantiate in onDraw?

Comment: To hit the desired 60fps and avoid a janky UI, you have ~16ms to measure, layout and draw the whole view hierarchy (also the system uses some of the ms). Depending on your view hierarchy this can be a fairly short time to get things done, so you want to do as much work as possible outside of those three methods. Instantiating objects is both time consuming and might cause the garbage collector to kick in, both wasting a lot of time and possibly frames.